# when building u-boot /bin/bash: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, gcc, arm, cross-compilation

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.0.4 on a 64 bit machine. I have an AM335X development board. Along with the kit came the compressed kernel (linux 3,2), rootfs, u-boot, and ARM cross compiler (arm-2010q1).

I uncompressed everything to a sub folder (/home/brent/work).

I have added the following to my .bashrc file:

```
PATH=/home/brent/work/arm-2010q1/bin:$PATH
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
```

I have also installed the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

When I go to built u-boot I am doing the following (per instructions that came with the kit):

```
brent@brent~/work/u-boot$ sudo make distclean
awk '(NF && $1 !~ /^#/) { print $1 ": " $1 "_config; $(MAKE)" }' boards.cfg > .boards.depend

brent@brent~/work/u-boot$ sudo make myd_am335x_lcd4.3_config
awk '(NF && $1 !~ /^#/) { print $1 ": " $1 "_config; $(MAKE)" }' boards.cfg > .boards.depend
Configuring for myd_am335x_lcd4.3 - Board: myd_am335x, Options: DISPLAY_LCD43

brent@brent~/work/u-boot$ sudo make
/bin/bash: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
/bin/bash: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
Generating include/autoconf.mk
/bin/bash: line 3: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
/bin/bash: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
Generating include/autoconf.mk.dep
/bin/bash: line 3: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
/bin/bash: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
/bin/bash: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
/bin/bash: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
/bin/bash: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld: command not found
/bin/bash: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
/bin/bash: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -DDO_DEPS_ONLY \
        -g  -Os   -fno-common -ffixed-r8 -msoft-float   -D__KERNEL__ -I/home/brent/CropVentures/u-boot/include -fno-builtin -ffreestanding -nostdinc -isystem  -pipe  -DCONFIG_ARM -D__ARM__         -march=armv5 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes      \
        -o lib/asm-offsets.s lib/asm-offsets.c -c -S
/bin/bash: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found
make: *** [lib/asm-offsets.s] Error 127
```

I have verified the binary is located at /home/brent/work/arm-2010q1/bin

I am also not sure why I need to have sudo as part of the command?  If I do not I get a permissions error.

Any help or information on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do the arm executables have their execute permission set?  If mounted, is your home not mounted with  "noexe"?  Try putting the PATH modifications into your .profile and ensure the export PATH is used.  Similarly for LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Check your arm tool chain if it is for 64-bit or not, you can use this command:

```
file <arm-tool-chain>/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

If it is not showing *elf 64 bit* then it won't work. Change the arm tool chain 32 bit to 64 bit.